# What does "follow forwards" mean?

Tags: finance, hedging, insurance

In the context of "if equity returns follow forward", what exactly does "follow forwards" mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does this quote come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this context it probably means that over time equity spot will move towards the forward.

For example: at t0 the spot S(t0) = 100, and assume divs are 0 and rate is 1%. Then the 1y forward would be 100*exp(0.01*1).

If spot would follow the forward, then after 6months the spot would have to be 100*exp(0.01*0.5).